# Remove blue cursor on touch screen with chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, multi-touch

I have a text field on a website. On touch screens, with chrome browser, a blue cursor apears when i select the text field.

Here is an example:

[image: blue cursor]

Is there any way to remove this?

Comment: That's inbuilt in Android or IOS systems, and currently there is no way to remove that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think their is an option to remove/hide this functionality via CSS or JS as this behaviour is native to Chrome as an application rather than a browser default front end style in the document window (for example this cursor appears in the URL bar as well as on pages).

From what I've read on the Google Product forums it would be a flag users would have to remove themselves on a case by case basis which unfortunately has not been implemented yet:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/T72xK1jZ5jo/99J-5_a_CQAJ

Answer (score 0):

Hiding cursor of all elements on small screen divices, also can remove the blue cursor on touch screen with chrome

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    * {
        cursor: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

[WacomTableProperties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z03f8.png)

Disable "Use Windows Ink" in your Wacom Tablet Properties

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).